# How can I build a dynamic parameter list for mailx command in bash linux?

Tags: bash, parameters, mailx

OS:  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)

I have a code sniplet:

```
!/usr/bin/env bash

v_mailx_parameter=""

v_cfg_email_adresse_to="john.doe_to@gmail.com"
v_cfg_email_subject="Report from December 2016"
v_tmp_email_text_name="Message Body"

v_email_main_file="appel orange.txt" # -> There is a SPACE in the file name! 
v_tmp_path="/home/server/tmp/"

if [ ! -z "${v_email_main_file}" ]
 then v_mailx_parameter="${v_mailx_parameter} -a \"${v_tmp_path}${v_email_main_file}\""
                                                 /\
                                                 ||
         Here is the problem but I need this because of spaces in the name
fi

echo -e "/bin/mailx ${v_mailx_parameter} -s \"${v_cfg_email_subject}\" \"${v_cfg_email_adresse_to}\""

cat ${v_tmp_email_text_name} | /bin/mailx ${v_mailx_parameter} -s "${v_cfg_email_subject}" "${v_cfg_email_adresse_to}"

exit
```

PROBLEM:
I want to build up the parameters to the mailx command dynamically.

But I want to use the " double-quotes because there can be spaces in the file names.

Unfortunately the example above does not work... because the mailx takes the double-quotes as if they belong to the file name...and I get an error message.

I do not want to use the if else condition.. because I have many of files I need to send... I need a dynamic solution.

Maybe it is better to understand what my problem is:

It works in such a hardcoded way:

```
cat ${v_tmp_email_text_name} | /bin/mailx -a "/home/server/tmp/appel orange.txt" -s "${v_cfg_email_subject}" "${v_cfg_email_adresse_to}"
```

But so NOT:

```
v_mailx_parameter="-a \"${v_tmp_path}${v_email_main_file}\""

cat ${v_tmp_email_text_name} | /bin/mailx ${v_mailx_parameter} -s "${v_cfg_email_subject}" "${v_cfg_email_adresse_to}"
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is covered in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an array, which can hold all the arguments to easy logging and invocation. Note, though, that the input redirection to feed the message to `mailx` is *not* an argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

v_cfg_email_adresse_to="john.doe_to@gmail.com"
v_cfg_email_subject="Report from December 2016"
v_tmp_email_text_name="Message Body"

v_email_main_file="appel orange.txt"
v_tmp_path="/home/server/tmp/"

if [ ! -z "${v_email_main_file}" ]; then
  v_mailx_parameters+=( -a "${v_tmp_path}${v_email_main_file}" )
fi
v_mail_x_parameters+=( -s "${v_cfg_email_subject}" )
v_mail_x_parameters+=( "${v_cfg_email_adresse_to}" )

printf '/binmailx %s < %s\n' "${v_mail_x_parameters[*]}" "${v_tmp_email_text_name}"
/bin/mailx "${v_mailx_parameters[@]}" < "${v_tmp_email_text_name}"
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use an array.

```
declare -a parameters=()

parameters+=(-option1 OPTION VALUE)
parameters+=(-option2 "VALUE WITH SPACES")
parameters+=("/path/with spaces")
parameters+=("$PATH_WITH_SPACES")
if
  some_condition
then
  parameters+=(-optionA)
else
  parameters+=(-optionB)
fi
mailx "${parameters[@]}"
```

The `"${parameters[@]}"` expansion is special in that it ensure each of the element is separately quoted, without performing word splitting or expansion on the actual value of the elements (like when using `"$@"`).